# How to change Selected Index when I only have the name?

Tags: javascript

I'm integrating Postcode anywhere with my web project. I'm using a drop drop for the county/state field. Postcode anywhere returns the name of the County. Can I change the Selected Index when I only have the name? (I'm using a number for the value field which relates to a database field).

I tried the following:

```
var f = document.getElementById("state_dropdown");
f.options.[f.selectedIndex].text = response[0].County;
```

I've tried to include the drop down code html here but I can't get it to work properly for some reason.

But of course this just changes the text field for the item in the drop down that is already selected.

I can query the database and find out what ID I have assigned the county but I'd rather not if there is another way.

Comment: Not 100% sure I get what you want. By changing the selected index with the name only do you mean with the content of the option tag (the visible string option)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the options until you have a match:

```
for (var i = 0; i < f.options.length; i++) {
    if (f.options[i].text == response[0].Country) {
        f.options.selectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/9D89J/)

Answer (score 2):

I would make a function and loop over the labels:

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3kYH/

```
<select id="country" name="countryselect" size="1">
<option value="1230">A</option>
<option value="1010">B</option>
<option value="1213">C</option>
<option value="1013">D</option>
</select>​
```

JavaScript

```
function selectElementByName(id, name) {
    f = document.getElementById(id);
    for(i=0;i<f.options.length;i++){
        if(f.options[i].label == name){
            f.options.selectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
selectElementByName("country","B");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a variation on other answers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function setValue(el, value) {
  var sel = el.form.sel0;
  var i = sel.options.length;
  while (i--) {
    sel.options[i].selected = sel.options[i].text == value;
  }
}

</script>
<form>
<select name="sel0">
  <option value="0" selected>China
  <option value="1">Russia
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="setValue(this, 'Russia');">Set to Russia</button>
<input type="reset">
</form>
```